# How to improve textmesh quality?

Tags: unity, fonts, text, pixel

In my game I using textmesh, but textmesh has a pixel problem even adjusting scale, character size and font size.  How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: With that said, these answers cover the subject pretty well: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/470635/3d-text-bad-quality-and-it-is-always-visible.html albeit they're on another website.

Comment: I already mention that textmesh has a pixel problem even adjusting scale, character size and font size . I already that